# How to avoid byte-compiler warnings when putting a defconst into a let?

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

I want to define a few constants in my emacs init file, based on running some code, like this:

```
(let* ((var1 ...) (var2 ...)
  ... more code here...
  (defconst env-is-ok (or var1 var2))
  (defconst env-is-v2 ...)
  (defconst env-is-v3 ...)

(if (and env-is-ok env-is-v2) ...do stuff...)
```

but I get a byte compiler warning on that last line, seemingly because the `defconsts` are not at top-level.

I think the code is semantically fine, so how do I convince emacs of that? Is there a good way to refactor so it's clearer to the compiler?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info